# Can I get the return type of all functions in an array?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Redux and typesafe-actions, and I want to get a type I can use to annotate in my reducer on the `action` parameter to get code completion for each of the string literal values of `action.type`.

Currently my setup is looking as such:

I have my actions defined using typesafe-actions:

```
export const increment = (amount: number) => action("INCREMENT", { amount });
export const decrement = (amount: number) => action("DECREMENT", { amount });
```

And I can then get my desired type like this:

```
export type CounterActions = ReturnType<typeof increment | typeof decrement>;
```

However this isn't ideal maintainability wise, because every time I add a new action, I have to remember to add it to the CounterActions type.

So my idea is to put all of my action creator functions in an array:

```
export const actions = [
    (amount: number) => action("INCREMENT", { amount }),
    (amount: number) => action("DECREMENT", { amount })
]
```

And then "spread" the array into `type CounterActions` somehow. This is where I'm stuck because I can't get the syntax right.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm probably missing something but it seems like your actions take a number and produce nothing (or an action?), so they all seem to have a unified interface `(x: number): void` or `(x: number): Action`.

Comment: Thank you for asking! `typeof increment` gives  `type: "INCREMENT";
    payload: {
        amount: number;
    };
}` and `typeof decrement` gives  `type: "DECREMENT";
    payload: {
        amount: number;
    };`.

Comment: I can use this in my reducer like this: ```const countReducer = (state = initialState, action: CounterActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return { ...state, value: state.value + action.payload.amount };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return { ...state, value: state.value - action.payload.amount };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typesafe-actions has a helper type called [ActionType](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#actiontype), which will do that union for you if you have a map object of the actions. The easiest way to do this is in another file, with an `import *`. For example:

```
import { ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions'
import * as counterActions from 'insert/filepath/here'

export type CounterActions = ActionType<typeof counterActions>;
```

In my application, we do this in a file for the RootAction, which just or's together all the actions we create throughout the app. So the file looks like:

```
import * as fooActions from './foo/actions'
import * as barActions from './bar/actions'
// etc

export type RootAction = 
  ActionType<typeof fooActions>
  | ActionType<typeof barActions>
  // etc
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed. Now I can define my actions like this: ```export const actions = {
    increment: (amount: number) => action("INCREMENT", { amount }),
    decrement: (amount: number) => action("DECREMENT", { amount })
}``` and get the desired type like this ```export type CounterActions = ActionType<typeof actions>;```